# How to spread database records on multiple columns?

Tags: php, mysql, html, html-table

I have this code for print a multi columns table from mysql

```
$k="<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='5'><tr>"; 
$h=mysql_query("select * from news order by id desc limit 0,12");
$col=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($h)){
    $col++; 
    $k .="
    <td>
    Text here
    </td>
    "; 
    if($col==3){
        $k .="</tr><tr>";
        $col=0;    
    }  
}
$k .="</tr></table>";
echo $k;
```

I want to add a random columns inside this table like ad-sense codes and I want the ad-sense code to display once per column.

the output should be like this

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
        <td>ADV Code1</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ADV Code2</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
        <td>ADV Code3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ADV Code4</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]<br>
        description : $row[full]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can i do this?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "adding random columns" ? Do you want to add "random cells" in your 3 columns table containing advertisements ?
How many cells are displayed originally ? How many "random advertisement cells" do you want to add ?...

Comment: the original cells are 3 and i want to random adver cells is 1 inside the original 3 cells

Comment: @Pin what is your question exactly? You are seeing the `<td>`'s, what is keeping you from injecting them with whatever content you like?

Comment: i have 3 cells showing .. i need to add a random cell for (advertisment ) inside the 3 cells

Comment: @Pin so what is keeping you from adding it?

Comment: i editted my original post please look at it you will find what exactly i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer + a few recommendations :

- Separate **data retrieving** and **display instructions**.
- Improve code readability : give relevant names to your variables (what is `$h` and `$k` ?)

Your code, after adding the "random advertisements", should look like :

```
$columns_number = 3;

// data retrieving

$ar_advertisements = array('advert1', 'advert2', 'advert3', 'advert4');

$mysql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12");
$ar_news = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result))
  $ar_news[] = $row;


// display : merge news with 'random advertisements' on each table row

$html = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5"><tr>';

$ad_displayed_on_row = false;
$advert_index = 0;
$cell_index = 1;

foreach ($ar_news as $news)
{
  // new row every X columns
  if ($cell_index > $columns_number)
  {
    $html .="</tr><tr>\n";
    $cell_index = 1;
    $ad_displayed_on_row = false;
  }

  // ensure that an advertisement is displayed only once for each table row, at a random position
  if ((mt_rand(1, $columns_number) == 1 && !$ad_displayed_on_row && $cell_index < $columns_number)
    || ($cell_index == $columns_number && !$ad_displayed_on_row))
  {
    $html .= "<td>".$ar_advertisements[$advert_index]."</td>\n";
    $ad_displayed_on_row = true;
    $cell_index++;

    $advert_index++;
    if ($advert_index >= count($ar_advertisements))
      $advert_index = 0;
  }

  // here I'm supposing that your 'news' table contains a 'text' field,
  // you should modify it to your convenience.
  if ($cell_index <= $columns_number)
  {
    $html .="<td>".$news['text']."</td>\n";
    $cell_index++;
  }
}

// complete last row with empty cells if necessary
// If you don't want them to by empty, just change &nbsp; by whatever you want
// complete last row with empty cells if necessary
if ($cell_index != 1)
{
  while($cell_index <= $columns_number)
  {
    $html .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    $cell_index++;
  }
}

$html .="</tr></table>";

echo $html;
```

Comment: i got this error ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting '; ) in line ( for($ar_results as $result_index => $result){ )

Comment: Aww sorry, didn't see this "I want to add a random columns inside this table like ad-sense codes and I want the ad-sense code to display once per column."... My answer doesn't matches exactly your specs

Comment: i fixed it be replacing (for) with (foreach)

Comment: i saw your code but it is not what i am looking for ..... i want to add one cell for advertisment inside my original 3 cells. by your code it displayed but the 3 original codes arrangement is wrong some times it shows 2 columns and some times shows 1 column per line. what i need is a one advertiment cell in side my 3 original cells so the total cells per row is ( 3 ).

Comment: Ok I've tested and fixed it. Should work now (just check what is the name of the  "text" field you want to display from your `news` table).

Comment: this is the data what i want to output (( <div class='bigtextb1'><a title='$name' href=\"shownews,$id.html\">$name</a></div>
<div style='float: right;padding:4px;'><img src='thumb.php?file=news_images/$img&sizex=80&sizey=80'/></div>
<div style='padding:2px;'>".truncatenews($full,'shownews,'.$id.'.html')."</div>   ))

Comment: please check my post i editted it i hope you will get my point .... i need to print exactly 12 cells

Comment: If you have 4 possible advertisements, simply fill the `$ar_advertisements = array(...)` at the beginning with what you want. And if you want exactly 12 cells, add a "LIMIT 8" to your SQL query so you will have 8 news + 4 advertisements.

Comment: check this http://img851.imageshack.us/i/colq.jpg/ and also http://img268.imageshack.us/i/col1l.jpg/

Comment: @Pin how about learning how to do this stuff yourself, or hiring somebody to do it. SO is not a custom code writing service.  http://www.elance.com/

Comment: i need to show 12 cells from my database and inside each <tr> i want 2 <td> of my database and 1 <td> from advertisment.

Comment: Ok last edit, enough time spent there... Upvote/accept please.

Comment: it still the same dear ... but i accepted your answer and thank you very very very much for your support.

Comment: When I test it on my machine, cells are shown (borders etc), only the cell content is empty...
BTW thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be appropriate

```
$h=mysql_query("select * from news order by id desc");

if($h){
    echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='5'><tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($h)){
        echo "<tr>";

        /**
        ...
        echo "<td>".$row['field']."</td>";
        echo other stuff
        as well as your random stuff
        ...
            **/
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```